# Java GSON deserialize JSON when name of object is an Integer

Tags: java, json, gson

first of all i know how to deserialize JSON Objects in general. The specific problem i've got is that i have a Json object which contains arrays named `"1", "2", "3"`, etc. but in Java i cannot declare the variable `ArrayList<AnotherObject> 1;` Is there a better way than replacing the numbers by hand?

Json (greatly reduced):

```
{
    "object": {
        "1": [{...}],
        "2": [{...}],
        "3": [{...}],
        "4": [{...}],
        "5": [{...}],
        "6": [{...}],
        "7": [{...}]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: array name like 1,2,3 is not a good practice.

Comment: Maybe read it into a `Map<Integer, ...>`?

Comment: @want2learn Of course not but unfortunately i cant change what i get from an API.

Comment: @yegodm I wouldn't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use `GSON` to deserialize your JSON:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String json = "{\n" +
        "    \"object\": {\n" +
        "        \"1\": [{ \"id\" : 111 }],\n" +
        "        \"2\": [{ \"id\" : 222 }],\n" +
        "        \"3\": [{ \"id\" : 333 }]\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}\n";
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .create();
    final ObjectWrapper value = gson.fromJson(json, ObjectWrapper.class);

    System.out.println(value.object);
    System.out.println(value.object.keySet());
    System.out.println(value.object.get(1));
}

// This is top-most object we want to deserialize from JSON
static class ObjectWrapper {
    // Didn't bother about proper naming while it is better to give a meaningful name here
    private Map<Integer, List<Element>> object;
}

static class Element {
    // Added this attribute to demonstrate that objects within array are properly read
    private int id;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{id=" + id + "}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers seem lot like indexes of an array. If that's so you can just delete all of them and make the whole object an array. So you will get an array of arrays.

Comment: I assume you mean this: `"array": [ [{...}], [{...}] ]`
That would work because the arrays in fact do represent days in a week. I could just replace every `"1":`, sure. But i'd rather not touch the JSON. Is there a way to create a mapping for GSON to use a different variable name?

Comment: Not really. You should basically use string replace but I doubt that it can go well. And since you know that the json is not in a good format why not changing it?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following workaround now:

```
json.replace("\"1\"","\"one\"")
    .replace("\"2\"","\"two\"")
    .replace("\"3\"","\"three\"")
    .replace("\"4\"","\"four\"")
    .replace("\"5\"","\"five\"")
    .replace("\"6\"","\"six\"")
    .replace("\"7\"","\"seven\"");
```

EDIT: This solution did work but it was pretty ugly. The solution from @yegodm works way better! Thank you for that!

Answer (score -1):

The way to solve the problem is to make the code that converts your JSON string in the following way:

```
{
    "object": {
        "a1": [{...}],
        "a2": [{...}],
        "a3": [{...}],
        "a4": [{...}],
        "a5": [{...}],
        "a6": [{...}],
        "a7": [{...}]
    }
}
```